# Best way to Iterate trough an Array with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I want to make a simple memory game with react for a neat portfolio project. I have an array of 20 items and 10 sets of colors

```js
    const data = [
      // Manchester Blue
      {
        ID: 1,
        Color: "#1C2C5B"
      },
      {
        ID: 2,
        Color: "#1C2C5B"
      },

      // Seafoam Green
      {
        ID: 3,
        Color: "#93E9BE."
      },
      {
        ID: 4,
        Color: "#93E9BE."
      },

      // Candy Apple Red
      {
        ID: 5,
        Color: "#ff0800"
      },
      {
        ID: 6,
        Color: "#ff0800"
      },

      // Lake Placid Blue
      {
        ID: 7,
        Color: "#3f5c9"
      },
      {
        ID: 8,
        Color: "#3f5c9"
      },

      // Safety Orange
      {
        ID: 9,
        Color: "#ff6700"
      },
      {
        ID: 10,
        Color: "#ff6700"
      },

      // Vivid Orchard 
      {
        ID: 11,
        Color: "#cc00ff"
      },
      {
        ID: 12,
        Color: "#cc00ff"
      },

      // Apple Green
      {
        ID: 13,
        Color: "#8db600"
      },
      {
        ID: 14,
        Color: "#8db600"
      },

      // Old Moss Green 
      {
        ID: 15,
        Color: "#867e36"
      },
      {
        ID: 16,
        Color: "#867e36"
      },

      // Canary Yellow
      {
        ID: 17,
        Color: "#ffef00"
      },
      {
        ID: 18,
        Color: "#ffef00"
      },

      // Pink
      {
        ID: 19,
        Color: "#ff1493"
      },
      {
        ID: 20,
        Color: "#ff1493"
      }
    ];
```

## I have the following basic HTML and CSS

### HTML

```
    <div>
      <div className='flexbox-container'>
        <div id='1' className='flexbox-item-one'></div>
        <div id='2' className='flexbox-item-one'></div>
        <div id='3' className='flexbox-item-one'></div>
        <div id='4' className='flexbox-item-one'></div>
        <div id='5' className='flexbox-item-one'></div>
      </div>
      <div className='flexbox-container'>
        <div id='6' className='flexbox-item-two'></div>
        <div id='7' className='flexbox-item-two'></div>
        <div id='8' className='flexbox-item-two'></div>
        <div id='9' className='flexbox-item-two'></div>
        <div id='10' className='flexbox-item-two'></div>
      </div>
      <div className='flexbox-container'>
        <div id='11' className='flexbox-item-three'></div>
        <div id='12' className='flexbox-item-three'></div>
        <div id='13' className='flexbox-item-three'></div>
        <div id='14' className='flexbox-item-three'></div>
        <div id='15' className='flexbox-item-three'></div>
      </div>
      <div className='flexbox-container'>
        <div id='16' className='flexbox-item-four'></div>
        <div id='17' className='flexbox-item-four'></div>
        <div id='18' className='flexbox-item-four'></div>
        <div id='19' className='flexbox-item-four'></div>
        <div id='20' className='flexbox-item-four'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
  .flexbox-item-one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: darkcyan;
    margin: 1.5rem;
  }

  .flexbox-item-two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    margin: 1.5rem;
  }

  .flexbox-item-three {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: slateblue;
    margin: 1.5rem;
  }

  .flexbox-item-four {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: magenta;
    margin: 1.5rem;
  }

  .flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

I also have done some research and procured the following way to shuffle the array.

```js
  let shuffledColors = colors
    .map(value => ({ value, sort: Math.random() }))
    .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
    .map(({ value }) => value)
```

So my React skills are just not to the level where I can build this. I want to have an useEffect hook that loads the array when the project is rendered and uses the shuffle method. It would then have to dynamically add the colors to the HTML elements. SOmething which I'm not entirely sure how to do as well. Maybe an ForEach statement that uses the document.GetElementByID to add the css dynamically.

I would then have to get a way with positions to have two divs on top of each other which I can have the top one dynamically have its opacity altered on a onClick event to show the 'real colors'

Then there would have to be a check if the ID's of the colors match and a counter which keeps track of how many matches have been made.

For now I just want to get my head around how to have this array of colors randomised and assigned to the divs when loaded with the useEffect hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's do it.

First, create a **FlexboxContainer** component that return a **div** with `flexbox-container` className:

```
const FlexboxContainer = ({ children }) => {
  return <div className="flexbox-container">{children}</div>;
};
```

Next, create a **FlexboxItem** component, where the show/hide logic resides. Here, we don't need a stack of two divs. Instead, we use conditional **backgroundColor** styling that depends on **actualColor** state on a div. Here, we do have a **onClick** handler that would set the **actualColor** by using **setActualColor** setter once the user clicks the color card div. The show/hide (toggle) action would be based on the previous state of **actualColor**.

```js
const FlexboxItem = ({ id, color, group }) => {
  const [actualColor, setActualColor] = useState();

  const handleClick = () => {
    setActualColor((prevState) => (!prevState ? color : undefined));
  };

  return (
    <div
      id={id}
      onClick={handleClick}
      className={`flexbox-item-${group}`}
      style={actualColor ? { backgroundColor: color } : null}
    ></div>
  );
};
```

At the main component, we need to define **currentColors** state where we put our **shuffledColors**.

```js
const [currentColors, setCurrentColors] = useState();
```

and we use **useCallback** hooks on **shuffledColors**

```js
  const shuffledColors = useCallback(() => {
    return data
      .map((value) => ({ value, sort: Math.random() }))
      .sort((a, b) => a.sort - b.sort)
      .map(({ value }) => value);
  }, []);
```

since the **shuffledColors** going to be used inside a memoized **groups** constant where we re-structure the **shuffledColors** into groups of colors.
The aim of this grouping is to provide an array that is going to be used to render a dynamics group of five color divs by using the iteration of **FlexboxContainer** component.

```js
  const groups = useMemo(() => {
    if (!currentColors) return [];
    const chunkSize = 5;
    const groupedItems = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < currentColors.length; i += chunkSize) {
      const chunk = currentColors.slice(i, i + chunkSize);
      groupedItems.push(chunk);
    }
    return groupedItems;
  }, [currentColors]);

  ...
  
  return (
    ...
    <div>
        {currentColors &&
          groups.map((items, index) => {
            return (
              <FlexboxContainer key={index}>
                {items.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <FlexboxItem
                      id={item.id}
                      color={item.color}
                      group={groupColors[index]}
                      key={item.id}
                    />
                  );
                })}
              </FlexboxContainer>
            );
          })}
      </div>
      ...
    )
}
```

Next, we define a shuffleColors method, by which we can use it to set the initial colors inside a **useEffect** hook.

```js
  const shuffleColors = useCallback(() => {
    const colors = shuffledColors();
    setCurrentColors(colors);
  }, [shuffledColors]);

  useEffect(() => {
    shuffleColors();
  }, [shuffleColors]);
```

If we want to **re-shuffle** the colors, just call it from **onCLick** handler. Here we do a minor modification at **FlexboxItem** component and add a **currentColor** watcher.

```
  const FlexboxItem = ({ id, color, group, show }) => {
    const [actualColor, setActualColor] = useState();
   
    // add show props change watcher
    useEffect(() => {
      setActualColor(show ? color : undefined);
    }, [color, show]);
    ...
  }

  ...

  // current color watcher will reset showAll state on any currentColors state change
  useEffect(() => {
    setShowAll(false);
  }, [currentColors]);

  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={shuffleColors}>Re-shuffle Colors</button>
    ...
  )
```

It does not fully answer your question, at least, will give you new insight into how React works to achieve your objectives.

Here is the complete code of my explanation:

[image: Edit loving-lalande-9bw761]